# Delphi 7 cyrillic characters not showing correctly

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, cyrillic

i recently asked (and paid) for translation of my Delphi app to support Macedonian (Cyrillic font) support.
I posted text to translate to my contracted translator, she sent me back translated strings. The text was extracted from all my .dfm and .pas files

when i replaced the original text with cyrillic translation, i can open .dfm fies also .pas files in my favourite Notepad++ (or notepad) , and i see translated characters correctly.

When i open these files in Delphi (as dpr file) , i see something like this:

[image]

Please someone tell me how to convert/display these strings in Delphi correctly. 
I am using Macedonian regional settings, but it not helped me with this problem.

PS: Yes I am still using Delphi 7 because i love it / purchased this version.

**UPDATE**

Original text in Delphi:
original:  ÐŸÐžÐ”Ð“ÐžÐ¢Ð’Ð˜ ÐšÐ£Ð¢Ð˜Ð˜ Ð—Ð Ð”Ð Ð£Ð“Ð˜Ð¢Ð• Ð¦Ð•ÐÐ¢Ð ÐÐ›Ð˜

Correct text:
ПОДГОТВИ КУТИИ ЗА ДРУГИТЕ ЦЕНТРАЛИ

I noticed, when i change ParentFont property to false and font set to Verdana and Cyrillic (RUSSIAN_CHARSET) , then i copy/paste cyrillic text, it shows normally in Delphi

Comment: The repeated character suggests the strings are in some form of Unicode but are being displayed as 8 bit ASCII with a code page in Delphi.  It would he helpful if you posted an actual string or two as text and as a series of hex values so those looking to answer can figure out the encoding used.

Comment: We don't have code. We don't know what fonts you have installed. We don't know whether you use tnt Unicode library. We cannot understand why you would attempt international code in an tool that can't do it natively.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan what code you want? Source code is not important, i replaced EN text with Cyrillic text, nothing else..  I mean in all caption values of .dfm file. I am not using tnt unicode library

Comment: You need to enter the macedonian in the proper relevant encoding, and make sure that the clients run their windows with their locale set to macedonian/cyrillic. There is no unicode support in D7, so it is all about making the "A" encoding match.

Comment: Why have you chosen a tool that is so unsuited to this task?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan first i made this app for EN speaking countries. Now i got offer fo Balkan regions , this is the reason. So first i had the app / tool for creating, then the problem. Life is not easy

Comment: Got to windows control panel.Region , administrative tab and choose Macedonian after pressing change system locale.Inform if it solved your problem

Comment: Choose the right tools

Comment: @DavidHeffernan please understand that this app is 8 years old, this time it was a right tool for my customers. That's all for you, i am not communicating with you anymore, because you are not trying to help me

Comment: @ShahramBanazadeh as i mentioned in main post, i already did that, but not helped me

Comment: @FeHora post some examples of the strings already.

Comment: @Brian see my update on original post

Comment: The right tools. Either Unicode Delphi or TNT Unicode components with Delphi 7. This is the help you need, although you can't see it. Personally, when I did this with my code I took the first option.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan credits to you, i am happy that you motivted me to solve this problem.. see my solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so i **SOLVED** that!

The solution is multi step one, and Notepad++ is needed:

**1st step**: Replace all fonts in .dfm with (for example) Verdana , or some font that allows Cyrillic support

**2nd step**: Replace all `ParentFont = False`  to `ParentFont = True`

**3rd step:** In notepad++  Choose: Encoding -> **Convert to ANSI**

that's all, do this for all .dfm and .pas file (only 3rd step)

i am happy to not Listened David Heffernan and not gave up!

Comment: David did give you some good advice.  ANSI encoded applications can still have rendering problems based on locale.  For example, a Macedonian user who happens to have an English version of Windows but still wants to use your program with the Macedonian localization will not see the text rendered correctly (without resorting to hacks).  Given that it is 2019, upgrading to a Unicode based solution is still the best option for you as it allows the application to integrate seamlessly in any particular user context.  It also makes it much easier to support other languages in the future.

Comment: I not changed simple piece of code last 6 years.. so upgrade/update was not needed :)  now new region = new problems, that i solved..   but I understand your point

Answer (score 0):

Your text file was UTF-8 encoded, whereas Delphi7 requires WinAnsi encoding, with codepage 1251 for Cyrillic characters.

You have the `UTF8Decode()` function in System.pas to make the conversion programmatically, if you prefer.

Comment: Adjustment: [CP-1251](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251) covers Cyrilic script languages. [CP-1250](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250) is for central/eastern European languages like Polish, Czech, Slovak, ...

Comment: @PeterWolf You are right, of course! Thanks for the input.